# Avoid hard coded databases credentials in combination with shell - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have written a Cakephp 3 shell application which uses models and behaviors to generate thumbnails. Since I populated the database credentials through the $_SERVER super global I need to manually insert the credentials. However, when I try the following snippet of code this results in an error saying that I can't overwrite the connection:

```
public main($host, $username, $password, $db){
    ConnectionManager::config('default', [
      'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
      'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
      'persistent' => false,
      'host' => $host,
      'username' => $username,
      'password' => $secret,
      'database' => $db,
      'encoding' => 'utf8',
      'timezone' => 'UTC',
      'cacheMetadata' => true,
    ]);
    ........
}
```

Moreover, it first tries to load my default settings in config/app.php which aren't populated and throws notices and errors:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME']) && isset($_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME']) && isset($_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD']) && isset($_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME']) ) {
   define('RDS_HOSTNAME', $_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME']);
   define('RDS_USERNAME', $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME']);
   define('RDS_PASSWORD', $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD']);
   define('RDS_DB_NAME', $_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME']); 
}
return [
.......
    'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => RDS_HOSTNAME,
        /**
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => RDS_USERNAME,
        'password' => RDS_PASSWORD,
        'database' => RDS_DB_NAME,
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

Is there any way to avoid hard coding of the database credentials in this way?

Comment: You could use environment variables, not familiar with cakephp but it seems like this helps out https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-environments

Comment: Okay. I will look in to that, thanks :).